# Run JavaScript in mongo shell gives syntax error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to run arbitray JavaScript from the mongo shell via 'load("myfile.js")' and it is giving me this error:

```
E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
```

The specific JavaScript I am trying to run looks like:

```
var cursor = db.movies.find({"year": "$not": { "$type": 16} });
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var x = cursor.next();

    /* replace invalid characters in x's strings ... */

    var p = parseInt(x.year.substring(0,4), 10)

    db.movies.update({_id : x._id}, p);
}
```

From the error is seems that something may need to be escaped but I am not sure what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mongodb query seem to be missing a block. Try this

```
var cursor = db.movies.find({"year": { "$not": { "$type": 16 } } });
```